# What does the sucks mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Between the trees the air seemed scarcely to move. The heat had
>   thickened it, so that the winged insects sat torpid on the very leaves
>   beneath which crouched the mantis and spider, too drowsy to strike.
>   Along the foot of a tilted, red rock a porcupine came nosing and
>   grubbing. It broke open a tiny shelter of sticks and some meagre,
>   round-eared little creature, all eyes and bony limbs, fled across the
>   stones. The porcupine, ignoring it, was about to devour the beetles
>   scurrying among **the sucks** when suddenly it paused, raised its head and
>   listened.

It is again a quotation from *Shardik* by Richard Adams. Only possible definition of **suck** seemed to fit the situation I found is [an act or instance of sucking; or sound produced by sucking](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sucks). But how the beetles can scurrying among the sucks if the porcupine was just **about** to devour them. Though right now I think this is also nonsense: the porcupine doesn't suck at least to devour something. And I just thought it also can be an epithet to some object mentioned before (but if it is then I can't recognize which one), for this case I put as much context as possible.
So I'm really confused about the meaning of **the sucks** here.

Comment: Colloquial term for a marsh/bog? Whatever it is, it's non-standard.

Comment: @Catija, hmm the sucks is a good epithet for a marsh, at least I can imagine it.

Comment: Do you have a link to the text ? Are you sure it's not a misprint for the earlier mentioned *sticks*

Comment: Would that fit into the context of the story? It sounds like they're in a forest, so it may work.

Comment: You have encountered a typographical error. The passage [in Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=SVMQBwAAQBAJ&pg=PT14) reads *The porcupine, ignoring it, was about to devour the beetles scurrying among the sticks…*.

Comment: @choster Yup, that's what I was thinking....

Comment: I don't know that the question deserves a downvote for being about a typographical error. It was asked in good faith. Closed, yes... downvoted, no.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an apparent typographical error in the book edition. See the comments for a link to the correct text.

Comment: @Catija - Absolutely the right call. Considering the downvote button's tooltip reads, "This does not show any research effort," I don't think that's the right button to click.

Comment: @choster, Thank You! It is quite disappointing to spend so much time trying to understand and learn that it's just a typo.

Comment: @Vitaly It seems the typo does not exist in the book, so what text were you reading?

Comment: @AlanC - Probably an scanned version. These are known as OCR errors, and they're not all that uncommon.

Comment: @AlanCarmack Yes, probably some scanned version, as J.R. said. At least it is in .doc. format.

Comment: @ J.R, should I delete this question, or it is better to leave it?

Comment: I'd leave it, even if it's going to be closed. A lot of people could benefit from reading the clear and careful way you worded this.

Comment: What @J.R.♦ said. The question is well posed, and it's no fault of OP's that it's just an OCR error. Besides, that duff text might be around for a long time (it might even be repeated in future online editions), so it's at least *possible* someone else will hit exactly the same problem.

Comment: Are you sure it’s a typo? *suckers* are shoots growing around the base of a tree.